# How to select based on an allowlist/blocklist using jq

Tags: text-processing, jq, filter

Using `jq`, how can we select json elements from an array based on inclusion/exclusion of each element's key in some allowlist/blocklist?

I want to do a case-insensitive contains (so allowlist/blocklist case would not matter).

Here is what I tried (not implemented blocklist):

```bsh
allowlist='["happy", "good"]'
blocklist='["sad", "bad"]'

jq  --argjson allowlist "$allowlist" \
    --argjson blocklist "$blocklist" \
    '.[]
    | select(.my_key | ascii_downcase
    | contains($allowlist[]))' \
<<< '[{"my_key": "neutral"}, {"my_key": "neutral good"},
     {"my_key": "neutral bad"}, {"my_key": "good"}, 
     {"my_key": "bad"}, {"my_key": "happy sad bad"}, 
     {"my_key": "neutral happy sad"}]'
```

Expected output:

```json
{"my_key": "neutral good"}
{"my_key": "good"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `select`, `any` and `all`, your filter comes down to

```
jq  --argjson allowlist "$allowlist" \
    --argjson blocklist "$blocklist" '.[] | 
        select( any ( .my_key ; contains( $allowlist[] ) ) ) | 
        select( all ( .my_key ; contains( $blocklist[] ) | not ) )'
```

Add `ascii_downcase` to the value of `my_key` in the above filter, if you needed `contains` to work with all lower case.